# How can i import and properly run pip imported libraries on lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I imported `boto3` for my lambda function in python. When i test lambda it gives this error : `No module named boto3` which is rather expected.
Then i referred to the docs,to this link to be exact https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html and realized i need to create a deployment package the issue is i didn't understand the docs well enough to keep up and would like them to be explained again in a simpler way by someone that has already done the required steps.

Comment: you don't need to install boto3 library separately, copy and paste your function to Lambda it will work fine.

Comment: correct i adjusted that part but i need to import `api.ai` so the problem stays.

Comment: ok i will write the steps.

Comment: @sid8491 you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210904/python-adjustment-for-user-input-in-lambda if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a folder in your local system, install the required libraries into that folder, zip the contents of the folder and upload the zipped file to the AWS Lambda.

- **Make a folder in local system**

I don't think you need help in this. Lets suppose you made a folder in D drive named yellow-bot

- **Install the required libraries into the folder**

You can install the required packages in the folder using below command

```
    pip install {package-name} -t "{path-to-project-dir}"
```

In your case it would be:

```
    pip install apiai -t "D:\yellow-bot"
```

- **Zip the contents of the folder**

Now after installing the required libraries there will be multiple files and folders in your yellow-bot folder. You need to select all and zip the content. **Please note that do not zip the folder, instead you go inside the folder and zip the contents.**
It would be something like below screenshot.
[image: yellow-bot]

- **Create lambda function and upload zip**

Now go to AWS Lambda, create a lambda function, give correct run-time and all that. Then `select upload zip` file in `code entry type`. Select your zip and click on upload.
Make sure to give correct `Handler`.
It follows naming convention as:

> The filename.handler-method value in your function. For example,
>   "main.handler" would call the handler method defined in main.py.

[image]
Since in this case I have uploaded `connector.py` file and entry function was called `lambda_handler()` so correct `Handler` would be `connector.lambda_handler`

Click on `Save` and you are done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Took the same route but couldn't save because it says fix the errors before u can save

Comment: It just says unsaved changes..fix the errors before saving.

Comment: Fixed it but another issue appeared, went to the logs and it still doesn't recognize api.ai, the exact error message is `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named apiai` .

Comment: Oh i work on linux so the compression wasn't zip by default, i noticed and fixed that.

Comment: So, what to do when we modify the python code, do we have to zip and upload all the time or can we just modify the code.

Comment: @arqam once you upload the zip file, all files can be opened in it's online editor (assuming its not too big). you can edit their, or can uplaod the zip file again.

Comment: @sid8491 Thanks for the reply.
So only when we need to add a new library then only we have to add the new .zip file right?

Comment: @arqam yes. but i like to do development on local system so i upload zip file everytime. one more thing, if your zip file is very large (i think more than 200mb) then you need to upload it on s3 and give link here.

Comment: @sid8491 zip file limit is 50 MB, if bigger you need to upload it to S3, and give the link to upload zip file from S3

Comment: IMPORTANT: One thing to note: The files should be zipped in Linux env. If files are zipped in Windows env, it won't work.