# OSError: libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory from aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mediainfo

I am using `pymediainfo` in lambda function , and I have followed the answer from [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206412/how-can-i-import-and-properly-run-pip-imported-libraries-on-lambda) .
The function has the below code

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
s3_bucket_file_key = 'https://s3-region.amazonaws.com/sample-bucket/sample_video.mov'
media_info = MediaInfo.parse(s3_bucket_file_key)
media_info_json = media_info.to_json()
```

Can someone please help me , the sample bucket is public , and I can run this code on my system . but getting the below error from `Cloudwatch` in `aws-lambda`.

It seems like libmediainfo is a os related package, I am not sure how to export it to the python deployment package.

```
anupam:Videos$ apt-cache search libmediainfo
libmediainfo-dev - library reading metadata from media files -- headers
libmediainfo-doc - library for reading metadata from media files -- documentation
libmediainfo0v5 - library for reading metadata from media files -- shared library
```

error

```
libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 166, in lambda_handler
media_info = MediaInfo.parse(key)
File "/var/task/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 183, in parse
lib = cls._get_library(library_file)
File "/var/task/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 155, in _get_library
return CDLL("libmediainfo.so.0")
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 357, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I added `libmediainfo.so.0` manually to the command

```
media_info = MediaInfo(video_file, library_file='path/to/libmediainfo')
```

I am getting the below error now for `libzen.so.0`

```
libzen.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/erlabs.py", line 166, in lambda_handler
media_info = MediaInfo.parse(key,library_file='libmediainfo.so.0')
File "/var/task/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 183, in parse
lib = cls._get_library(library_file)
File "/var/task/pymediainfo/__init__.py", line 146, in _get_library
return CDLL(library_file)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 357, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libzen.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to include everything needed in your deployment package for the lambda to work properly, see if [this](https://markn.ca/2018/02/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/) helps

Comment: Thanks @yorodm, will look into the post you mentioned